# Do derived classes need to implement move semantics when a base provides it?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I finished reading [Thomas Becker's "C++ Rvalue References"](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html). I have a couple questions on Rvalues and Rvalue references.

Suppose I have a simple array class:

```
template <class T>
MyArray
{
    ...
    T* m_ptr;  // Pointer to elements
    size_t m_count; // Count of elements
};
```

Further suppose it provides:

```
#if(__cplusplus >= 201103L)
MyArray(MyArray&& t)
  : m_ptr(std::move(t.m_ptr)), m_count(std::move(t.m_count))
{
    t.m_ptr = NULL;
    t.m_count = 0;
}
MyArray operator=(MyArray&& t)
{
    std::swap(*this, t);
    return *this;
}
#endif
```

Now, suppose I have a derived class that does *not* add new data members:

```
MyImprovedArray : public MyArray
{
    ...
};
```

What is required of `MyImprovedArray`?

Does it need a `MyImprovedArray(MyImprovedArray&&)` and `MyImprovedArray& operator=(MyImprovedArray&&)` also? If so, does it only need to perform the base class `std::move`? Or does it need to perform the `std::swap` too?

```
MyImprovedArray(MyImprovedArray&& t)
    : MyArray(t)
{
}
```

Comment: In doubt, you may still do `MyImprovedArray(MyImprovedArray&&) = default;`

Comment: As long as you don't have a virtual base, the defaults are fine. If you have a virtual base, [you may need to take a look at your copy/move assignment operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252869/danger-with-virtual-base-move-assignment-operators-when-they-are-now-allowed-to).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rule of five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11) (or zero) applies to the derived class, regardless of what the base class defines.

If your derived `MyImprovedArray`'s move constructor isn't going to do anything special, don't define it, and let the compiler generate one.

Comment: So I'm clear, that means I don't need to write anything in `MyImprovedArray`? That is, the declaration and `: MyArray(std::move(t))` (and empty body) are spurious? (Sorry to ask. In C++ I've been bitten a few times with the *"don't pay for it when you don't need it"* mantra. It ended poorly with virtual destructors).

Comment: Correct (aside from a constructor obviously). If you do not define a destructor, move constructor, copy constructor, move assignment operator, or copy assignment operator then the compiler will make them for you (assuming the class is copyable/movable based on its members)